# Two queries returning different number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble pinpointing exactly why query #1 is returning less records than query #2:

QUERY #1

```
with
cte_biggie ([NPI],[Year Entered],[Month Entered],[Count],[Practice Name],[MLIS Code],[Practice Code],
        [Physician],[Sales Rep],[Date Established],[Address],[Address2],[City],[State],[Status]) as (
select c.npi, DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered])  , 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01 THEN 'Jan' 
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 02 THEN 'Feb'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 03 THEN 'Mar'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 04 THEN 'Apr'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 05 THEN 'May'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 06 THEN 'Jun'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 07 THEN 'Jul'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 08 THEN 'Aug'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 09 THEN 'Sep'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 10 THEN 'Oct'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 11 THEN 'Nov'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 12 THEN 'Dec'
           END
           ,COUNT([specimen id])  ,[practice name],b.[mlis practice id],a.[practice code],[Requesting Physician],c.salesrep,
   c.dateestablished , c.practiceaddress1, c.practiceaddress2,c.practicecity,c.practicestate,
    b.[Active Inactive]
from quicklabdump a
    inner join qlmlismapping b
    on (b.[practice code] = a.[practice code])
    inner join PracticeandPhysician c
    on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME
        and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode)
where   ( [Date Entered] >= '20100101' AND [Date Entered] < '20120101')


group by DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]), DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]), a.[practice name],b.[mlis practice id],a.[practice code],
    a.[Requesting Physician],c.salesrep,c.dateestablished, c.practicecity,c.practicestate,c.npi,c.practiceaddress1 ,c.practiceaddress2,
    b.[Active Inactive]


)

select [Original December Count]=SUM([count])  from cte_biggie
where [Year Entered]=2011
and [Month Entered]='Dec'
```

the result is

```
79009
```

whereas this query:

```
QUERY# 2

;with
cte_biggie2 ([Year Entered],[Month Entered],[Count]) as (
select  DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered])  , 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01 THEN 'Jan' 
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 02 THEN 'Feb'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 03 THEN 'Mar'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 04 THEN 'Apr'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 05 THEN 'May'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 06 THEN 'Jun'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 07 THEN 'Jul'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 08 THEN 'Aug'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 09 THEN 'Sep'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 10 THEN 'Oct'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 11 THEN 'Nov'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 12 THEN 'Dec'
           END
           ,COUNT([specimen id]) 
from quicklabdump 
where   ( [Date Entered] >= '20100101' AND [Date Entered] < '20120101')


group by DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]), DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered])

)

select [Original December Count2]=SUM([count])  from cte_biggie2
where [Year Entered]=2011
and [Month Entered]='Dec'
```

is returning:

```
108357
```

I do not understand how this can be happening since I am returning THE SAME THING in both queries, I'm just choosing to display more columns in the first one.

It seems like the `join` that i am performing is actually limiting the results. Why does this happen?

Comment: See jeff Atwood's [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) which quite clearly shows that JOINs (especially INNER JOIN) actually **reduces** the amount of data selected....

Comment: Not relevant to your question but I encourage you to learn about the built-in DateName function.  With it, you can replace your case statement and also make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the `inner join` clauses in the first query that are making the difference. With an inner join, the result set will only include rows from the left-hand table where there are matching rows in the right-hand table.

You can include all rows from the left-hand table with a `left join`. Even with a left join, though, the number of rows in the final output is likely to be affected.

**EDIT**

Here's a simple example of how an inner join can limit the rows in the resultset:

```
Authors:

Author_ID    Name
---------    --------
1            "Fred"
2            "Susan"
3            "Bob"

Posts:

Post_ID      Author_ID     Abstract
---------    ----------    ----------
1            1             "Joel Spolsky is my hero..."
2            2             "My co-worker is crazy..."
```

Selecting from only `Authors` (with no condition) returns all rows (obviously). But querying from both `Authors` and `Posts` with an inner join, like this:

```
SELECT a.Name, p.Abstract
FROM Authors a
JOIN Posts p ON p.Author_ID = a.Author_ID
```

produces this result:

```
Name        Abstract
--------    -----------
"Fred"        "Joel Spolsky is my hero..."
"Susan"       "My co-worker is crazy..."
```

Notice that even though we are querying the `Authors` table, "Bob" does not appear in the results...because he hasn't authored any posts (apparently). If we change the join to a left join, like this:

```
SELECT a.Name, p.Abstract
FROM Authors a
LEFT JOIN Posts p ON p.Author_ID = a.Author_ID
```

the result will look like this:

```
Name        Abstract
--------    -----------
Fred        "Joel Spolsky is my hero..."
Susan       "My co-worker is crazy..."
Bob         NULL
```

Note: The fact that I am returning a column (`Abstract`) from the second table in the join (`Posts`) makes no difference to the number of returned rows.

Comment: but why would it limit the results. wouldnt it increase the results?

Comment: @I__ `INNER JOIN` causes the query to exlude any records that do not have a match in **both** tables involved in the `JOIN` (+1 for this very quick answer, by the way).